# Why thread sanitizer complains about this std::ranges::views::filter code?

Tags: c++, race-condition, c++20, range-v3

When running this code thread sanitizer [complains](https://www.godbolt.org/z/7WoqGK) about data race.
Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::vector v{11,22,33,44,55,66};
    auto view = v | std::ranges::views::filter([](const auto x){
        return x>47;
    });
    std::jthread jt1([&]{
    int sum =0;
    for (const auto& val: view) {sum+=val;}
    });    
    std::jthread jt2([&]{
    int sum =0;
    for (const auto& val: view) {sum+=val;}
    });
}
```

note: I know answer to this, I learned it recently watching a talk, but I found it very surprising and no existing questions related to this, so I wanted to share it. If nobody is interested in answering I will answer it myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[&]` in a thread-running lambda should immediately ring an alarm. It is generally not safe to pass random objects by non-`const` reference to threads. In particular, it is not thread-safe to invoke non-`const` member functions on standard library objects.

`begin` is not a `const` member function of `std::ranges::filter_view`.

> `constexpr iterator begin();`
> Expects: `pred_.has_value()`.
> Returns: `{*this, ranges::find_if(base_, ref(*pred_))}`.
> Remarks: In order to provide the amortized constant time complexity required by the range concept,
> this function caches the result within the `filter_view` for use on subsequent calls.

In libstdc++ implementation, it's this exact caching operation that trips the thread sanitizer.

An attempt to make `view` constant results in a compilation error.

The same is true about `reverse_view`.

Other range adaptor do have `const` overloads for `begin`.

It is possible to work around this in practice by calling `view.begin()` before constructing the threads. I don't know if this makes undefined behaviour officially go away (I think it probably should), but it does silence the sanitizer.